# What should the source be when using OpenVPN?

Tags: 10.04, openvpn, iptables, vps

I'm trying to use OpenVPN on my Ubuntu 10 VPS.

I'm trying to route my traffic using this command:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/24 -j SNAT -to
```

The error I get is:

```
iptables v1.4.4: You must specify --to-source
```

What should the source be?

Answer (score 2):

You have to specify where you want the traffic to go to

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/24 -j SNAT --to-source aa.bb.cc.dd
```

where "aa.bb.cc.dd" is where you want the traffic to go.

See also

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OpenVPN

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/IptablesHowTo